# Comparison test help

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

I've worked out (b) (i) through the ratio test and I realize that comparison test should be used for (ii) but I'm unsure how to do this with a root n on top, or if your meant to relate it to (i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler if you use equivalents: $3n+1\sim_\infty3n$, hence
$$\frac{2\sqrt n}{3n+1}\sim_\infty \frac{2\sqrt n}{3n}=\frac23\frac1{\sqrt n},$$
which diverges.

Comment: Cheers, for the response

Answer (score 0):

For two notice that $$\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{3n+1}\geq \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{3n+n} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ so $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{3n+1}$$

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer